# Histogram with log-scaled in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, statistics, histogram

Hello I have an array let's say a and then I do this :

```
b = np.array([math.log10(i) for i in a])
```

And then I do `hist(b)`

But I prefer to see like this 10^-7 instead of -7 for the x axis. So I tried `plt.xscale('log')` but I get : "Data has no positive values, and therefore can not be log-scaled." So it is strange because I can do hist(b).

So do you know how to solve this ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: The issue is that your values aren't 10^-7, they are -7, 10^x = i, in your case 10^-7 = i, it is very unclear what you are actually attempting to do with this. You won't be able to do any scaling to get it to actually show up as 10^-7.